# What does IFormatProvider do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iformatprovider

I was playing around with the `Datetime.ParseExact` method, and it wants an `IFormatProvider`...

It works giving `null` as input, but what exactly does it do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider) need the IFormatProvider?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961520/why-datetime-parseexactstring-string-iformatprovider-need-the-iformatprovide). I'm voting to close with a newer one because it is worded better, and has better answer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In adition to [Ian Boyd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18195374/3283073):

Also `CultureInfo` implements this interface and can be used in your case. So you could parse a French date string for example; you could use

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourDateInputString, yourFormatString, ci);
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an overload that matches your example anymore in the .NET Framework 4.6.  You must use `DateTime.ParseExact(string, string, IFormatProvider)` instead, I believe - as such:  `DateTime.ParseExact("20160409 111559","yyyyMMdd HHmmss",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`

Comment: In .NET Framework 4.6.2 there is no input parameters as you point. I use only two and it works fine `DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(yourDateInputString,  ci);` Please revise your answer.

Comment: Sorry guys, a long overdue update has been made to my answer.

Answer (score 59):

The `IFormatProvider` interface is normally implemented for you by a `CultureInfo` class, e.g.:

- `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`
- `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`
- `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`
- `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-CA") //German (Canada)`

The interface is a gateway for a function to get a set of culture-specific data from a culture. The two commonly available culture objects that an `IFormatProvider` can be queried for are:

- [`DateTimeFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo): `IFormatProvider.GetFormat(typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo));`
- [`NumberFormatInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo):  `IFormatProvider.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo));`

The way it would normally work is you ask the `IFormatProvider` to give you a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo? format;
format = (DateTimeFormatInfo)provider.GetFormat(typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo));
if (format != null)
   DoStuffWithDatesOrTimes(format);
```

There's also inside knowledge that any `IFormatProvider` interface is likely being implemented by a class that descends from `CultureInfo`, or descends from `DateTimeFormatInfo`, so you could cast the interface directly:

```
CultureInfo? info = provider as CultureInfo;
if (info != null)
   format = info.DateTimeInfo;
else
{
   DateTimeFormatInfo? dtfi = provider as DateTimeFormatInfo;
   if (dtfi != null)
       format = dtfi;
   else
       format = (DateTimeFormatInfo)provider.GetFormat(typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo));
}

if (format != null)
   DoStuffWithDatesOrTimes(format);
```

## But don't do that

All that hard work has already been written for you:

**To get a `DateTimeFormatInfo` from an `IFormatProvider`**:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo format = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider);
```

**To get a `NumberFormatInfo` from an `IFormatProvider`**:

```
NumberFormatInfo format = NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider);
```

The virtue of `IFormatProvider` is that you create your own culture objects. As long as they implement `IFormatProvider`, and return objects they're asked for, you can bypass the built-in cultures.

You can also use `IFormatProvider` for a way of passing arbitrary culture objects - through the `IFormatProvider`. E.g. the name of god in different cultures

- god
- God
- Jehova
- Yahwe
- יהוה
- אהיה אשר אהיה

This lets your custom `LordsNameFormatInfo` class ride along inside an `IFormatProvider`, and you can preserve the idiom.

In reality you will never need to call `GetFormat` method of `IFormatProvider` yourself.

Whenever you need an `IFormatProvider` you can pass a `CultureInfo` object:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

endTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

transactionID.toString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("qps-ploc"));
```

> **Note**: Any code is released into the public domain. No attribution required.

Answer (score 22):

Passing null as the `IFormatProvider` is not the correct way to do this. If the user has a custom date/time format on their PC you'll have issues in parsing and converting to string. I've just fixed a bug where somebody had passed null as the IFormatProvider when converting to string.

Instead you should be using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Wrong:

```
string output = theDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss.fff", null);
```

Correct:

```
string output = theDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Is there any reason we should use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`?

Comment: InvariantCulture is a special culture which is guaranteed to always exist on any machine and will always convert and parse back to the same values. CurrentCulture is the culture of the current thread. This can vary and if you don't use the same culture to convert to string and parse, you'll get format errors...

Comment: @StephenBooher passing in `null` will default to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. See the call in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#bfc8add12515d311), if you follow the chain of calls along, the null eventually gets replaced with [`DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.currentinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) which is equivalent to what `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` outputs.

Comment: InvariantCulture is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[IFormatProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx) provides culture info to the method in question. [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) implements IFormatProvider, and allows you to specify the format you want your date/time to be displayed in. Examples can be found on the relevant MSDN pages.

Answer (score 4):

You can see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx

See the remarks and example section there.

Comment: Ironically the sample code for `IFormatProvider` doesn't use `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 3):

By [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx)

The .NET Framework includes the following **three** predefined IFormatProvider implementations to provide culture-specific information that is used in formatting or parsing numeric and date and time values:

1. The `NumberFormatInfo` class, which provides information that is used to format numbers, such as the currency, thousands separator, and decimal separator symbols for a particular culture. For information about the predefined format strings recognized by a `NumberFormatInfo` object and used in numeric formatting operations, see Standard Numeric Format Strings and Custom Numeric Format Strings.
2. The `DateTimeFormatInfo` class, which provides information that is used to format dates and times, such as the date and time separator symbols for a particular culture or the order and format of a date's year, month, and day components. For information about the predefined format strings recognized by a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object and used in numeric formatting operations, see Standard Date and Time Format Strings and Custom Date and Time Format Strings.
3. The `CultureInfo` class, which represents a particular culture. Its `GetFormat` method returns a culture-specific `NumberFormatInfo` or `DateTimeFormatInfo` object, depending on whether the `CultureInfo` object is used in a formatting or parsing operation that involves numbers or dates and times.

The .NET Framework also supports custom formatting. This typically involves the creation of a formatting class that implements both IFormatProvider and ICustomFormatter. An instance of this class is then passed as a parameter to a method that performs a custom formatting operation, such as `String.Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])`.

Answer (score 2):

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx for the API.

Answer (score 1):

The [DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) class implements this interface, so it allows you to control the formatting of your DateTime strings.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks about IFormatProvider and DateTime, but you can use IFormatProvider also in other contexts of .NET, such as for string.Format.

Then you pass in the IFormatProvider instance and you can by implementing IFormatProvider specify how the string is formatted for an object. So the usage of IFormatProvider and a related ICustomFormatter interface is more broad in .NET than just for dates.

E.g. consider this implementation :

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class EmployeeProductivityFormatProvider : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {
        public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            int rating = (int)arg;

            if (rating == 0)
            {
                return $"{rating} (new employee)";
            }

            if (rating > 0)
            {
                return $"{rating} (good employee)";
            }

            return $"{rating} (bad employee)";
        }

        public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
        {
            if (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter))
            {
                return this;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we can get a string representation of an employee by specifying an int value like this:

```
    string prod = string.Format(new EmployeeProductivityFormatProvider(),
                                "Productivity rating: {0}",
                                employee.ProductivityRating);
```

When it comes to DateTime, there are a lot of already created IFormatProvider implementation to choose from. This is a very flexible way of representating objects to strings and specifying their format in .NET and a very general concept.

Comment: Exactly the implementation i was looking for. I am trying to construct a Type Mapper pipeline. Your answer helped me with the last piece of puzzle.  Source Type -> Primitive Type Conversion (using Func <Source.Target> for now) ->Type-Constraint Identification (using predicates) -> Type Formatter Application (using IFormatProvider and iCustomFormatter) -> Target Type . I dream of a day when computer can auto cast a type.