# How to convert string to a DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, converters

is it possible to convert a `string` (date stored as `varchar` in database) to `datetime` in c#?

eg. i'm having a table which stores dates as varchar and it stores values as example

`01/21/14 11:42:36 PM`

i want to get the result in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`

i tried,

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/21/14 11:42:36 PM", "yyyy-mm-dd", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
```

**also tried below steps:**

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime("01/21/14 11:42:36 PM");
string dt = Convert.ToString(d);
DateTime.TryParseExact(dt, "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);
var output = d.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

getting value `1/1/0001 12:00..` in `dt`.

what could be the reason? also in which format do i need to pass the date (`dt` in above case) to `DateTime.TryParseExact(..)`

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't *have* a format. The format you pass into `TryParseExact` is the format *of the string you're trying to parse*.

Comment: _"table which stores dates as varchar "_ that's a problem with greater priority.

Comment: Obviously dates should never be stored as varchar. Also MMDDYY is not the date format in most of the world. Are you looking for a solution that is hard-code to this specific situation, or one more general?

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter of your call should be the format you're passing. After the datetime is created you can specify the output format:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact("01/21/14 11:42:36 PM", "MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss tt", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out d);

var output = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: getting value 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM id d

Comment: @user3085995: I suspect `TryParseExact` is returning `false` then - you shouldn't ignore that.

Comment: The `ToString` should use `MM`, not `mm`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: what could be the reason that `TryParseExact` returns `false`

Comment: @user3085995: Well we don't know whether you're using the *exact* input you've shown us so far or not. But presumably the input doesn't match the given format. It's hard to say any more without knowing what you're passing in.

Comment: @JonSkeet: please see my edited question above.as i'm first converting the `string` to `DateTime` i'm getting value as `1/21/2014 11:42:36 PM`

Comment: @JonSkeet Good catch. I suggest you start simple. try to parse a simple format and work your way up to the complete string. I typed this format from memory and as Jon pointed out there was already an error. The main point is that the second arguments should match your input format.

Answer (score 0):

```
            String date = "01/21/14 11:42:36 PM";
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
            var output = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```