# Wed Mar 01 2017 invalid datetime string format

Tags: c#, string, datetime

My app has a DateTime picker control that send selected date in this format: "Wed Mar 01 2017", In server side I'm doing Convert.ToDateTime("Wed Mar 01 2017").
With everything date until today this work fine, but with "Wed Mar 01 2017" its throw Invalid format exception.
Why is that?

Comment: Check that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961520/why-datetime-parseexactstring-string-iformatprovider-need-the-iformatprovide

Comment: Please mark the correct answer and upvote the helpful answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` and specify the format like:

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact("Wed Mar 01 2017","ddd MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //invalid date
}
```

The reason it is failing on your machine is due to a culture that doesn't support the format, otherwise your code should work for `en-US` culture.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("Wed Mar 01 2017");
```

Just make sure that the culture is not changed on your machine.

To be on the safe side, it is always a better idea to parse the date using the format with `InvariantCulture` so that you can support your applications across multiple cultures.

Answer (score 0):

check [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime.ParseExcact("Wed Mar 01 2017","ddd MMM dd yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
var date = "Wed Mar 01 2017";
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddd MMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```