# Querying between two date values in asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a treatmentDate column in the database where dates to treated patients are submitted. If I need to generate report of Total Sum say between January 01 2015 and Jan 30 2015 for a particular company, how do I construct my query.

Below is what I have done and I'm having errors

```
            var treatmentSum = (from s in db.Treatments
                                where (s.CompanyId == CompanyID)
                                s.TreatmentDate >= fromDate && s.TreatmentDate <= toDate
                                select s.Amount).Sum();                
            ViewBag.TreatmentSum = treatmentSum;
```

Here's the treatment date column I want to search through.
[image]

Your guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: _" I'm having errors"_? What errors?

Comment: shouldn't there be an '&&' between **(s.CompanyId == CompanyID)** AND **s.TreatmentDate**

Comment: Any luck with the answers below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30263549/1837329

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post the error message. You are trying to compare strings using the <= and >= , instead try to handle all of your Date and Time variable as DateTime properties.
Here's a piece of code for the LINQ expression:

```
DateTime FromDate= Convert.ToDateTime("04/20/2015");
DateTime ToDate= Convert.ToDateTime("04/28/2015");
ViewBag.TreatmentSum = GetAllTreatments.
Where(c=>Convert.ToDateTime(c.TreatmentDate)>=FromDate &&
Convert.ToDateTime(c.TreatmentDate)<=ToDate).
Sum(c=>c.Amount);
```

Also Here's a link to a demo for your specific problem : https://dotnetfiddle.net/1a50HI

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch for your help. The resukts was generated and sent to a PDF view. So I can see the results directly in PDF now. Any ideas on how to take the entire PDF view and save in into the database? I used the rotavita PDF generator.

Comment: Post the code on a separate question for that and me or someone else will definitely help.

Comment: Hi thank once again. I have posted the question as suggested. You can find it here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298009/)

Answer (score 1):

You've got some formatting issues:

```
  var treatmentSum = (from s in db.Treatments
                            where s.CompanyId == CompanyID &&
                            s.TreatmentDate >= fromDate && s.TreatmentDate <= toDate
                            select s.Amount).Sum();                
        ViewBag.TreatmentSum = treatmentSum;
```

You had a where in the middle of the statement:

`where (s.CompanyId == CompanyID)` and you weren't separating it with `&&`

**Edit**

As stated the dates are in string, you could convert them inline, although be aware you may need to provide some [`CultureInfo`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506676/what-does-iformatprovider-do) so the formatter knows how to convert the date:

```
  var treatmentSum = (from s in db.Treatments
                                where s.CompanyId == CompanyID &&
                                Convert.ToDateTime(s.TreatmentDate) >= fromDate && Convert.ToDateTime(s.TreatmentDate) <= toDate
                                select s.Amount).Sum();
```

Comment: I added the `&&` to the query, I ran into another red squiggly line saying 
`Operator '>=' cannot be appied to operands of type 'string and 'string'` I actually have my date column in the database as a string datatype then used the datetime data annotation In my BOL.