# Inconsistency when parsing DateTime in the same format

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following strings:
`10/10/2021 00:00:00` and `18/11/2021 23:59:59`

I have this code:

```
    bool first = DateTime.TryParse("10/10/2021 00:00:00", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
        DateTimeStyles.None, 
        out DateTime firstDate);

    bool second = DateTime.TryParse("18/11/2021 23:59:59",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.None,
        out DateTime secondDate);

    Console.WriteLine(firstDate + " --- " + secondDate);
```

The output is:
`10/10/2021 12:00:00 AM --- 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`

As you can see the second date is not properly parsed, even though it's in the same format. What is the reason for that and how can I fix it?

Comment: The first date isn't parsed the way you think it is either. Try parsing `01/07/2021`. If you have a specific format to parse (in this case `dd/MM/yyyy`), use `TryParseExact`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does CultureInfo.InvariantCulture mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760237/what-does-cultureinfo-invariantculture-mean)

Comment: The second date isn't parsed incorrectly. It just has not been parsed. The value you see is just the default value. When you use a method starting with Try you should check the return boolean if the returned out parameter contains something useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *As you can see the second date is not properly parsed, even though it's in the same format.*

Here my [two cents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/two_cents#Noun).

Programming languages and frameworks are *not* smart enough to know which kind of format data you applied, specially for dates, times, numbers etc.. If you provide these data, you kinda *have to* provide the proper format as well so they can do their job. You "said" the same format, but you didn't apply any format in your code. So, as we humans, we know (at least you told us) but the computer don't know.

Let's look what [`TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-6.0#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) says;

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
> DateTime equivalent using the **specified culture-specific format
> information** and formatting style, and returns a value that indicates
> whether the conversion succeeded.

You didn't supply format information you supplied [`IFormatProvider`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/506676/447156) as [`InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-6.0). So, what are these "culture specific formats"?

Well, most of them are returns with [`GetAllDateTimePatterns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getalldatetimepatterns?view=net-6.0) method (but *not* all of them) but be aware because documentation says;

> You can use the custom format strings in the array returned by the
> `GetAllDateTimePatterns` method in formatting operations. However, if
> you do, the string representation of a date and time value returned in that formatting operation **cannot always be parsed successfully** by the
> `Parse` and `TryParse` methods. Therefore, you cannot assume that the
> custom format strings returned by the `GetAllDateTimePatterns` method
> can be used to round-trip date and time values.

So, if you run;

```
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns().Dump();
```

**`Dump` is just an extension method of [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) by the way, it just outputs to the console.*

You will get a lot of datetime patterns, but for our case, the important one is we get `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format for `InvariantCulture`.

As you can see, your `18/11/2021 23:59:59` data doesn't match with `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` format because there is no 18th [month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar#Months) on [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) which is a `DateTime` instance belongs internally.

Your second parsing fails by the way, that's quite different just saying "the second date is not properly parsed" and this is how `DateTime.TryParse` method works as explained in the documentation;

> When this method returns, contains the `DateTime` value equivalent to
> the date and time contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, or
> [`MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=net-6.0) (which is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`) if the conversion failed. The conversion fails if the s
> parameter is `null`, is an empty string (`""`), or does not contain a
> valid string representation of a date and time.

So, best way to handle this to supply a "specific" format using with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0) method or one of its overloads like;

```
bool first = DateTime.TryParseExact("10/10/2021 00:00:00",
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, 
    out DateTime firstDate);

bool second = DateTime.TryParseExact("18/11/2021 23:59:59",
    "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out DateTime secondDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The default DateTime format is 'MM/dd/yyyy' and since you have the date in 'dd/MM/yyyy' format it gives you the output.
Maybe try changing the date format input as `11/18/2021 23:59:59`